# Install Broadcom BCM4360 of MacBook Air CentOS 7, Installing system-release(25)

Tags: centos, wifi, rpm, macintosh, broadcom

I was trying to install my Wifi using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TG_EHEWHQuM

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# lspci | grep Wireless
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
[root@localhost Downloads]#
```

Here my **version of CentOS**

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

[root@localhost Downloads]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
[root@localhost Downloads]#
```

Now I list the rpm that I want to install

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# ls -al /home/liveuser/Downloads/*.rpm
-rw-rw-r--. 1 liveuser liveuser 23178 Aug 30 00:56 /home/liveuser/Downloads/rpmfusion-free-release-25.noarch.rpm
-rw-rw-r--. 1 liveuser liveuser 20386 Aug 30 00:56 /home/liveuser/Downloads/rpmfusion-free-release-26.noarch.rpm
-rw-rw-r--. 1 liveuser liveuser 23270 Aug 30 00:56 /home/liveuser/Downloads/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25.noarch.rpm
-rw-rw-r--. 1 liveuser liveuser 20430 Aug 30 00:56 /home/liveuser/Downloads/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-26.noarch.rpm
[root@localhost Downloads]#


[root@localhost Downloads]# rpm -ivh rpmfusion-free-release-25.noarch.rpm rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25.noarch.rpm
warning: rpmfusion-free-release-25.noarch.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 6806a9cb: NOKEY
warning: rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25.noarch.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID fa7a179a: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        system-release(25) is needed by rpmfusion-free-release-25-2.noarch
        system-release(25) is needed by rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25-2.noarch
[root@localhost Downloads]#
```

Using **yum localinstall**

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# ls -al
total 56
drwxr-xr-x.  2 liveuser liveuser  4096 Aug 30 02:16 .
drwx------. 16 liveuser liveuser  4096 Aug 30 01:54 ..
-rw-rw-r--.  1 liveuser liveuser 23178 Aug 30 02:16 rpmfusion-free-release-25.noarch.rpm
-rw-rw-r--.  1 liveuser liveuser 23270 Aug 30 02:16 rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25.noarch.rpm
[root@localhost Downloads]# yum localinstall --nogpgcheck rpmfusion-free-release-25.noarch.rpm rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Examining rpmfusion-free-release-25.noarch.rpm: rpmfusion-free-release-25-2.noarch
Marking rpmfusion-free-release-25.noarch.rpm to be installed
Examining rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25.noarch.rpm: rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25-2.noarch
Marking rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rpmfusion-free-release.noarch 0:25-2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: system-release(25) for package: rpmfusion-free-release-25-2.noarch
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.uniminuto.edu
 * extras: centos.uniminuto.edu
 * updates: centos.uniminuto.edu
---> Package rpmfusion-nonfree-release.noarch 0:25-2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: system-release(25) for package: rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25-2.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: rpmfusion-free-release-25-2.noarch (/rpmfusion-free-release-25.noarch)
           Requires: system-release(25)
Error: Package: rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25-2.noarch (/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25.noarch)
           Requires: system-release(25)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 3 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
ipa-client-4.4.0-12.el7.centos.x86_64 has installed conflicts freeipa-client: ipa-client-4.4.0-12.el7.centos.x86_64
ipa-client-common-4.4.0-12.el7.centos.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-client-common: ipa-client-common-4.4.0-12.el7.centos.noarch
ipa-common-4.4.0-12.el7.centos.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-common: ipa-common-4.4.0-12.el7.centos.noarch
[root@localhost Downloads]#
```

Again

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# yum localinstall --nogpgcheck --skip-broken rpmfusion-free-release-25.noarch.rpm rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25.noarch.rpm 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Examining rpmfusion-free-release-25.noarch.rpm: rpmfusion-free-release-25-2.noarch
Marking rpmfusion-free-release-25.noarch.rpm to be installed
Examining rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25.noarch.rpm: rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25-2.noarch
Marking rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rpmfusion-free-release.noarch 0:25-2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: system-release(25) for package: rpmfusion-free-release-25-2.noarch
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.uniminuto.edu
 * extras: centos.uniminuto.edu
 * updates: centos.uniminuto.edu
---> Package rpmfusion-nonfree-release.noarch 0:25-2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: system-release(25) for package: rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25-2.noarch

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    rpmfusion-free-release-25-2.noarch from /rpmfusion-free-release-25.noarch
    rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25-2.noarch from /rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25.noarch
[root@localhost Downloads]#
```

**Is it really possible to install this rpm's?**

NOTE: *The rpm for CentOS is not compatible with Broadcom rpm*

Answer (score 1):

To get the wifi working on centos 7 using the `BCM4360` you should build the `wl-kmod` package following the steps described on [elrepo.org-wl-kmod](https://elrepo.org/tiki/wl-kmod) .

To correctly build and load the `wl` you need to disable the secure boot or sign your kernel module.